# Как во flex контейнере отцентровать отдельный блок по вертикали

Tags: flexbox

Необходимо именно отдельный блок расположить по центру.
Почему container-small не располагается по центру?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="container-small">
</div>
</div>
<style>
.container {
display: flex;
padding: 0px;
background:black;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.container-small {
background:white;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
justify-self: center;
}
```

Comment: а какие свойства CSS свойства flex вы использовали, чтобы разместить блок по центру? И чтобы по вертикали встало - надо задать высоту родителя.

Comment: так вроде `flex` не имеет `justify-self`, это же про гриды